# there is a package or function in R that allows "Identifying Excel Entries that Add Up to a Specific Value"

Tags: r, excel, solver, value-of

I'm trying to perform the solver function to identify excel entries that add to a specific value with GRG non-linear resolution method in R, but so far I can't find specific information about it. The problem is almost the same as the following exercise [enter link description here](https://thedailycpa.com/2017/07/21/identifying-excel-entries-that-add-up-to-a-specific-value/), except for the method that would be GRG non linear. So my question is related to whether there is a package in R that allows solving it in the same way that excel does, because so far I have not been able to find it.
Maybe it is something easy to solve, but I still can't do it.
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: You are likely to get quicker and more help if you provide sample input data and sample expected output. (and any code you are working with) Also, avoid screen shots for data and code. Use code formatting option (Ctrl^K) as needed.

Comment: I would suggest to first write down the mathematical model. Once you have that, it is easier to see what type of solver you need.

Comment: @ShanR Thanks for your advice, I will edit my question so that it is better understood

Comment: @ErwinKalvelagen Thanks for your suggestion, I will edit my question so that it is better understood what I am looking for

Comment: R has its own packages for optimization. I don't see any point in using R to run Excel's Solver. Grab the data that you need from Excel and then invoke R's tools. Using GRG non linear for a subset-sum problem also sounds weird. Subset-sum is a classic NP-complete problem. It can be solved as an integer programming problem, but I don't think that continuous variable optimizers are very helpful. It is a thoroughly discrete problem.

Comment: @JohnColeman Thank you very much for your answer professor. He helped me a lot to support the fact that it was not a good idea to do this procedure in R. Very grateful for your help.